# Ignore "=" during link string

Tags: javascript, pentaho

noob user here.

In pentaho I used a script to access a link in a .mail file, it happens that inside the email the link is breaking in several lines, how do I make this script ignore the = sign that breaks the link?

Script:

```
var link = content.match(/(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|\b(?:[a-z\d]+\.))(?:(?:[^\s()<>]+|\((?:[^\s()<>]+|(?:\([^\s()<>]+\)))?\))+(?:\((?:[^\s()<>]+|(?:\(?:[^\s()<>]+\)))?\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))?/gi);

link = link.filter(function(i) {
    return i.indexOf('https://www.google.com/appserve/mkt/p') === 0
}).shift();


Alert(link)
```

link inside .mail file:
[**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmNlJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
link.replace("=","");
```

Thats all you need.